# Creating a Keystore with a signed der file and private key

Tags: openssl, keytool, digital-certificate

Currently, i have a der file and a private file, but currently i can't a proper documentation that allows me to create a jks keystore file based on the der and my private key.

What i have tried so far:

Create a pkcs12 file:

```
 openssl pkcs12 -export -in  received_ca_cert.der  -inkey mykey.key -certfile received_ca_cert.der -out test-keystore.p12
```

Error message:

```
unable to load certificates
```

I believe, that after solving that problem , i should use something like:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore test-keystore.p12  -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore test-keystore.jks -deststoretype  JKS
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`pkcs12 -export` requires all its input files -- privatekey and one or more certificates -- be in PEM format (as defined/extended by OpenSSL since actual PEM two decades ago didn't cover this). **Convert a certificate from DER to PEM** with:

```
openssl x509 -in certfile.der -inform DER -out certfile.pem
# you can specify -outform PEM but it's the default and hence unneeded
```

ALSO: You should not specify the same certificate as `-in` and `-certfile`. `-in` should be the certficate that matches the privatekey. If there is *another* cert or certs, including but not limited to chain cert(s), that you want to include, that's what `-certfile` is for. Whether such 'extra' cert(s) is(are) necessary or desirable depends on how your cert was issued, and to an extent who/what will need to verify it, which you haven't even hinted at in your question.

Note that if you have the chain certs in your truststore, either the default one or one you specify with `-CAfile` and/or `-CApath`, you can specify `-chain` and OpenSSL will automatically find/choose the needed chain certs for you; this may be easier than manually deciding what goes into `-certfile`.

And similarly you don't need to specify `-deststoretype jks` to `keytool` because it's the default.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but the main problem that we have right now is that our Integration Platform only accepts files in DER, an not PEM.